# What is unordered_set in C++

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set

Below is a block of code from leetcode, I'm wondering what does the second line mean. I never saw this kind of initializing set. Could anyone help? Thank!

```
 bool containsDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
    unordered_set<int> s (nums.begin(), nums.end());
    return s.size()!=nums.size();
 }
```

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set

Comment: unordered_set or unordered_map is faster than set or map since they don't keep keys sorted. So if you don't need sorted key, using unordered version helps the speed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++11 vector constructor copy vs range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121228/c11-vector-constructor-copy-vs-range)

Answer (score 3):

```
unordered_set<int> s (nums.begin(), nums.end());
```

This initializes the set by iterating over the specified `vector`, starting at the beginning of the vector and iterating until it reaches the end, calling `s.insert(theVal)` for each `int` in the `vector`.

```
return s.size()!=nums.size();
```

Since an `unordered_set`, by its nature, does not allow any duplicate keys to exist in the set (i.e. trying to insert a key into the set, while that key is already a member of the set, will not modify the set at all), then we know that if the final size of the set is less than the size of the input vector, that the input vector must have had at least one duplicate value in it.